# Error on trying to remotely access HBase

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hbase

I'm using the HBase API in java and I'm just running a test program to retrieve and create some records in HBase table. My HBase is configured on a Amazon EC2 linux instance. 
I'm trying to set the zookeeper IP and port but it gives me error below at  `.set`

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", HBaseConf.zookeeperIP);
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", HBaseConf.zookeeperPort);
```

It does not recognize the `.set` method and give syntax error. I have imported all the necessary packages but nothing helps. Can someone please tell me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HBaseConfiguration` object:

```
HBaseConfiguration conf = new HBaseConfiguration();
```

Comment: Still same error. Please check:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Mh8qOofl7QNElVelJKRkxyaEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know your jar version, but it might be:  `Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();` as well.

Comment: That also doesn't work for me. I'm using hbase-0.94.26.jar. 
Should I include hbase-site.xml in my eclipse project or not?

Comment: about the last error: you need to convert to string: `conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort",Integer.toString(HBaseConf.zookeeperPort));`

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know why is this error coming :(

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Hbaseconfiguration.create()`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Configuration conf = null;
/**
 * Initialization
 */
static {
    conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
}
```

if not work then do this,

add hbase/conf directory on classpath or if you are using eclipse/IDE then go to build path --> link source and add hbase/conf directory